# "Rounded", "heaping" and other types of teaspoon(fuls)?

Tags: measuring-units

Can you please elaborate what's "rounded" teaspoon, what's "heaped" teaspoon and what other "types" of teaspoons exists as a measures of volume?

And is there any difference between, rounded teaspoon and rounded teaspoon**ful**?

Comment: General reference for the first part (seriously, try putting "rounded teaspoon" into Google); no difference for the second part.

Comment: "Heaping"? Heaped, surely?

Comment: Definitely heaped - slim has this right

Comment: @slim and Rory: sorry, [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heaping+teaspoon%2Cheaped+teaspoon&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) shows 'heaping' is American and 'heaped' British.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have a teaspoon, which measures volume - usually in some ovular, concave measuring device.  Let's say you're measuring a teaspoon of something granular, like flour, coffee or sugar.

**1 tsp** (or **1 *level* tsp**) means that the top of what you're measuring is flat; no sugar goes above the top of the spoon.

**1 rounded tsp** means you scoop a spoonful of sugar, and let it form a small pile above the top of the spoon.  It is inherently less precise than a level teaspoon.

**1 heaping tsp** means you pretty much try to get as big a pile of sugar onto the spoon as you can, without spilling it.  It's a little over a smidgen more than a rounded teaspoon.  Helpful hint: Don't try to measure a heaping teaspoon when dealing with liquids.

[image]
No, the -ful suffix has no effect on the amount.

Comment: That's interesting - *heaping tsp* looks really weird to me, but a few seconds with NGrams confirms this is another of those [US/UK usage splits](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heaping+tsp%2Cheaped+tsp&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). The line for *heaped tsp* disappears completely when the corpus is restricted to American books - obviously they must almost all be the British usages, even though there aren't enough to graph at all when the corpus is restricted to British books.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Before this, I have not heard of "heaping" teaspoonfuls... sounds like hooting night-owls.. :)                      You will see the BrE contribution if you expand the tsp: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heaping+teaspoon%2Cheaped+teaspoon&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3

Comment: I believe it's a term used in cookbooks and recipes, but not much else.

Comment: “usually in some ovular *concave* measuring device” — what, like not a *convex* one, then? :)

Comment: @tchrist: only if you're measuring upside-down.  If that's how to do it, though, I'll pass on your cookies ;^/

Comment: Relatedly, in Australia we also have the unit "spoons of milo" or "spoonfuls of milo". This is a material-specific idiosyncrasy in that a) the implement is always assumed to be at least a tablespoon (there is no such thing as a "teaspoon of milo"), b) it is always of much greater quantity than "heaped" of other materials, and c) there is no singular, it is always plural.

Comment: I think rounded means you should knock off the peak as well. I got here because I have a very flat (large diameter) teaspoon as well as a deep one (smaller diameter). I guess the amount of material will just have to depend on which spoon I grab. Actually, I'll interpret "1 rounded teaspoon" as a scant 2 teaspoons. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is also the "scant teaspoon" ([example here](http://recipes.howstuffworks.com/tools-and-techniques/what-does-scant-mean.htm)). It's slightly less than a level teaspoon.

Note that "scant" sometimes means "barely" but in this context it means "not quite."