# The content, added to the container that sticks out of it

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the name for the content of a container (such as glass, spoon or Tupperware), that sticks out above the rim of that container? You can see the example on the image.

[image]

The word spoonful is probably not applicable since the spoon is overflown.

Comment: It is usually referred to as a "heaped (tea)spoonful".

Comment: 'Overfill' as a noun only seems to have been used attributively as yet. Perhaps an OEDophile like @WS2 could check for head noun usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There are two noun entries for "overfill". The first is said to be obsolete and there are no examples since the 13th century. So I think we can forget that. This is the other - a very specific use *A projection on rolled metal produced when the amount of metal is too large for the aperture or groove into which it is forced in rolling, so that the excess spreads into the junction between the rolls. Also: a bar, etc., that is too large for the rolling it is to undergo. Cf. underfill n., flash n.2 Compounds 2.*

Comment: @WS2: While the *entire* content of the spoon might be called a “heaped (tea)spoonful”, the question seems to be asking about just the part that sticks up above the level of a, well, level spoonful — so that might be called a “heap”?  But the spoon is just an example.  The question wants a more general term; for example: a scoop of ice cream usually sticks up above the level of the dish, and the whipped cream on a milk shake sticks up above the level of the glass.

Comment: @Scott How about "the amount of sugar excess to a level teaspoonful"? If it has been discovered that there is no single word which says that, I'm not entirely surprised.  But wouldn't the word "surplus"help in some way?

Comment: @WS2 Doesn't it even give the modern (if fairly rare) attributive usages like 'overfill prevention system',  'overfill prevention valve', 'overfill volume'? I've also found 'for ensuring that fuel spills or overfills do not occur' and 'the valve helps prevent tank overfills', but these obviously refer to processes. However, 'Anatomy of an overfill' in this article [Wiley Online Library: Endodontic Topics](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1601-1546.2009.00238.x) may be referring to the physical result. But it could be referring to filling over something rather than overfilling.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No. Though there is of course an entry for the verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your picture would be described as a *heaped teaspoonful*, a common expression in recipes and the like. I'm not aware of any particular term for a larger container; you would just have to say it was 'heaped up' or 'overflowing' with sugar or whatever.

Comment: *Heaping teaspoonful* sounds more natural to me. In general, also see ELU's [“Rounded”, “heaping” and other types of teaspoon(fuls)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59711/rounded-heaping-and-other-types-of-teaspoonfuls)